Intuition for Planck-Einstein relation for other particles than photons
The Planck-Einstein relation E=hf for photon can be extended for any other particle. Describing total energy this way feels relatively intuitive for photon, at least partly because we have easily understandable experimental results. Is there any easy explanation/ intuition why total energy of any particle can be described with this relation? Is there any experiments that show this? I am quite a beginner with modern physics. Intuitively E=hf feels more like a kinetic energy for some massive particle.

I would recommend the de Broglie thesis

The 3blue1brown video explains the thesis - The more general uncertainty principle, beyond quantum

The Schrodinger equation applies to everything:
$$i\hbar \frac{d\Psi}{dt} = H\Psi.$$
Solving this equation gives:
$$\Psi = e^{-iHt/\hbar}\Psi_0,$$
where $\Psi_0$ is some initial state.  If we're in an eigenstate of energy, then this becomes
$$\Psi = e^{-iEt/\hbar}\Psi_0,$$
where $E$ is the energy.  Therefore, the angular frequency is equal to $E/\hbar$, which is what we wanted to prove.

Is this not mildly circular, since one motivates the Schrodinger equation via $E=hf$ and now we have used the Schrodinger equation to "prove" $E=hf$?

Maybe mildly circular, but a). There are many ways that E = hf could be instantiated, the Schrodinger equation being only one of them, and b) the fact that Schrodinger equation applies to absolutely every system in existence explains why we see the same phenomenon in both photons and massive particles.
